# How to Group by date in Firebase Realtime Database in Flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, group-by

I want to grouping data list from Firebase Real time database with flutter. This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart'; // for formatting timestamp to datetime
import 'package:collection/collection.dart'; // for collection

class PlugModel {
  var key;
  var data;
  String hour;
  String minute;
  String day;
  String month;
  String year;

  PlugModel(this.key, this.hour, this.data);

  PlugModel.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot)
      : key = snapshot.key,
        data = snapshot.value['data'],
        hour = DateFormat.H().format(
            DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(snapshot.value['time'])),
        minute = DateFormat.m().format(
            DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(snapshot.value['time'])),
        day = DateFormat.yMd().format(
            DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(snapshot.value['time'])),
        month = DateFormat.yM().format(
            DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(snapshot.value['time'])),
        year = DateFormat.y().format(
            DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(snapshot.value['time']));
}

class Plug extends StatefulWidget {
  final String data;
  final String userId;
  final String id;

  Plug({this.userId, this.data, this.id});

  @override
  _PlugState createState() => _PlugState();
}

class _PlugState extends State<Plug> {
  List _plugList;

  final FirebaseDatabase _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  StreamSubscription<Event> _onDeviceAddedSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _plugList = [];

    var _deviceQuery = _database
        .reference()
        .child(widget.userId)
        .child(widget.data)
        .child(widget.id);
    _onDeviceAddedSubscription =
        _deviceQuery.onChildAdded.listen(_onEntryAdded);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _onDeviceAddedSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _onEntryAdded(Event event) {
    setState(() {
      _plugList.add(PlugModel.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  }
}
```

So, i suppose my `List` (`_plugList`) will be like this:

```
_plugList = [
    PlugModel('1', 2.3, '1', '11', '2019-11-11', '2019-11', '2019'),
    PlugModel('2', 2.5, '2', '33', '2019-11-11', '2019-11', '2019'),
    PlugModel('3', 2.4, '4', '18', '2019-11-12', '2019-11', '2019'),
    PlugModel('4', 1.4, '5', '26', '2019-12-22', '2019-12', '2019'),
]
```

Then, How to group my List according to date:

1. Grouping Daily

```
{
    '2019-11-11' : 
       { 
           ('1', 2.3, '1', '11'),
           ('2', 2.5, '2', '33')
       }
    '2019-11-12' :
       {
          ('3', 2.4, '4', '18')
       }

}
```

2. Grouping Monthly (Only need `Sum` of the all data in that month)

```
{
    '2019-11' : 
       { 
           (7.2),
       }
    '2019-12' :
       {
          (2.4)
       }

}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two things:

1. The items in the list need to be in the order that you want to group them on.
2. You'll need to keep track of the last "group by value" you've seen.

With those two out of the way, you can loop over the values in your list and group them with something like:

```
var _plugList = [
    PlugModel('1', 2.3, '1', '11', '2019-11-11', '2019-11', '2019'),
    PlugModel('2', 2.5, '2', '33', '2019-11-11', '2019-11', '2019'),
    PlugModel('3', 2.4, '4', '18', '2019-11-12', '2019-11', '2019'),
    PlugModel('4', 1.4, '5', '26', '2019-12-22', '2019-12', '2019'),
];
PlugModel lastPlug;
for (var i=0; i < _plugList.length; i++) {
  var plug = _plugList[i];
  if (lastPlug?.day != plug.day) {
    print("It's a new day, yes it is: "+plug.day);
    lastPlug = plug;
  }
  print("  "+plug.key);
}
```

The output:

> flutter: It's a new day, yes it is: 2019-11-11
>
> flutter:    1
>
> flutter:    2
>
> flutter: It's a new day, yes it is: 2019-11-12
>
> flutter:    3
>
> flutter: It's a new day, yes it is: 2019-12-22
>
> flutter:    4